# If $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{k}=\frac ba$ where $\frac ba$ is an irreducible fraction, then $b$ can be divided by $p^2$?

Tags: prime-numbers, summation, fractions

> **Question** : Is the following true for any prime number $p\ge 5$ ?
>
> If $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{k}=\frac ba$ where $\frac ba$ is an irreducible fraction, then $b$ can be divided by $p^2$.

**Motivation** : I've been interested in this summation. Then, I reached the above expectation. We can see this is true for smaller $p$.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{5-1}=\frac{5^2}{12},\sum_{k=1}^{7-1}=\frac{7^2}{20},\sum_{k=1}^{11-1}=\frac{{11}^2\cdot 61}{2520},\sum_{k=1}^{13-1}=\frac{{13}^2\cdot 509}{27720},\sum_{k=1}^{17-1}=\frac{{17}^2\cdot 8431}{720720}$$
So far I can neither find any counterexample even by using computer nor prove this is true for any prime number $p\ge 5$ ? Can anyone help?

Comment: Hmmm interesting... I wonder if it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is a corrollary of [Wolstenholme's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem).  The proof is [well-documented](http://www.math.uci.edu/~tchoi/notes/wolstenholme.pdf).

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. I'm happy to know it.